# inject @Value into a bean from a imported 3rd jar

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations

I have a bean(TokenJWTService) from an imported jar(common.jar)

```
 package com.xx.yy;
 public class TokenJWTService {

     @Value("${user.service.url}")
     private String userServiceUrl;

     //other methods
}
```

Now I want to inject a url into above bean's field `userServiceUrl` using @Value annotation

I tried to add `package com.xx.yy` to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.xx.yy " />` but the value is still not injected.

I also tried to `<bean id="tokenJWTService" class="com.xx.yy.services.TokenJWTService" p:userServiceUrl="${user.service.url}"/>` but injection failed too.

How can I inject a value into that bean, which leaves in an imported jar?

Comment: The `<bean id="..` approach should work. How do use use the bean then? You have to autowire it to some place for injection to work. Calling `new TokenJWTService()` yourself unsurprisingly results in stock Java behavior without injection.

Comment: Where is the user.service.url value coming from. If its from a properties file you need to register a property placeholder configurer pointing to the location of your properties file. For example if you have a properties file called application.properties with user.service.url=http://www.theservice.com then use <ctx:property-place-holder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved... thanks zapl.. your comments remind me to invesitgate further in a right drieciton..

I put `<bean id...` part in a wrong xml config file.
In web.xml, i registerd the bean in **spring-controller.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-controller.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

While it should be in **sso-config.xml**,

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:propertyFileConfigurer.xml
        classpath:sso-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```